# Single word antonym of "censorship"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms

What is a single word antonym of *censorship*? *Freedom of speech* is too long. I would like to be able to contrast it like:

> ignorance vs knowledge
>
> submission vs defiance
>
> oppression vs freedom

Comment: What's wrong with whatever you found in a thesaurus?

Comment: @simchona None of them really give me the association of freedom of speech: approval, compliment, encouragement, endorsement, praise, recommendation, sanction

Comment: @Lirik: Freedom of speech definitely *doesn't* imply any of those words you just listed. It means what it says - the freedom to say whatever you like. This has nothing to do with whether anyone else approves of it or not. I'm therefore voting to close because you haven't properly defined the meaning you want a word for.

Comment: @chessmath: I defend to the death Link's right to say what he does despite the fact that it's utter twaddle. Just as I defend millions of people's right to say that it was Voltaire who said *"I disapprove of what you say, but I will defend to the death your right to say it"*, despite the fact that it was actually [Evelyn Beatrice Hall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Beatrice_Hall)  in her 1906 biography. Freedom of speech is even better than playing fast and loose with words!

Comment: @FumbleFingers what on earth are you talking about? Did you even bother to read my question? Exactly what you do **think** was I  asking for here? And before you answer, please read my question again and read the answers (apparently, everybody else understand what my question is about).

Comment: @Lirik: I'm saying you have freedom of speech here. That does *not* imply that your question meets with my *approval, compliment, encouragement, endorsement, praise, recommendation, sanction*. If you'd asked for a phrase with those connotations it wouldn't be "*freedom of speech*" - nor would it be an antonym of "*censorship*".

Comment: @FumbleFingers My freedom of speech was never a part of this question and five people seem to have understood my question just fine. I don't blame you for being overly zealous about semantics, as this is the English stack exchange, but you probably do realize that English is not the native language of everybody here (including myself).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, Link asked for an antonym for "censorship". Simchona suggested consulting a thesaurus, whereupon Link listed the words he found in a thesaurus and said he found them unsatisfactory. You then say that because you agree with Link that a "general reference" did not provide a satisfactory answer, that this makes Link's question "twaddle"? So, what, if Link had said that he got a satisfactory answer from a general reference, that this would make the question valid? I thought that was one of the prime reasons for closing a question. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: @Jay: That's a rather forced interpretation of Link's question text and first comment. I took them at face value, to mean those were the qualities he associated with *freedom of speech*. Bearing in mind the accepted answer trivially shortened his own expression to simply *free speech*, I continue to maintain that everything he wrote apart from the title, and the sentence *"Freedom of speech is too long"* was at best irrelevant, and probably to most people actually misleading.

Comment: Right, in my first comment I pulled the dictionary antonyms of censorship and (as you and I agree) they don't mean free speech, so your following comment was, how do I say it, twaddle. I explicitly said in the first comment that "**none of [the dictionary antonyms] really give me the association of freedom of speech**," so I don't know how you can take that to mean that I associate them with freedom of speech. Marty's point was also correct: "if communication is the intent," then "free speech" works just fine. I didn't explicitly state it, but communication was in fact the the intent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How interesting! A forum on language and we appear to have a communication problem. :-) I interpreted Lirik's first comment to mean that these were the words he found listed as antonyms of censorship, and he did not consider them appropriate. You appear to have interpreted the comment to mean that he found some list of antonyms that he has not specified, and they are unsatifsfactory because they do not convey the ideas expressed in the list of words he gives, implying he considers these to be attributes of freedom of speech. How amusing. Language is a many splendored thing.

Comment: @Jay,Link: In standard English, if you terminate a clause with a semicolon, and follow it with a list, the default interpretation is that the list corresponds to the immediately-preceding syntactic element - in that case, *"the association of freedom of speech"*. I'm not a mind-reader - it seemed more likely to me that's what OP meant, since the alternative (which turns out to be true) is actually rather unusual. Native speaker or not, it's rather odd for anyone to be familiar with the term *"freedom of speech"* but not know the far more common *"free speech"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the preceding "syntactic element" was "**None** of them really give me the association of freedom of speech," then I listed the definitions that did not give me a strong association of freedom of speech. It's not that I didn't know "free speech," but at the time I was looking for a single word antonym and "free speech" never crossed my mind as a viable alternative. Again, I understand you're not a mind reader, but you're the only one saying that my question is twaddle and that it doesn't make sense. Everybody else seems to get it just fine...

Comment: @Lirik: Okay, you've made your point. But you chose to ask for an antonym of "censorship", when what you really wanted was a one-word synonym for *"free speech"* (or for *"freedom of speech"*, if you really didn't know the shorter and more common form). And as you should have realised, *"censorship"* has a far broader spread of meanings than the political sense you were interested in. If you'd just asked for a synonym for *"freedom of speech"* in the first place, things would have been a lot simpler.

Comment: ...if it makes you feel any better, I apologise for offending you with the words "utter twaddle". But please bear in mind this was a jokey response to a now-deleted comment made by chessmath, the day after I'd already said that the attributes you *appeared* to ascribe to "freedom of speech" did not in fact apply. You hadn't at the time replied to say that wasn't what you meant; I had no reason to think you had simply expressed yourself unclearly, and that I had misunderstood you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I feel like we just did one of these: http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: haha good one! Okay - let's not fall out over this. Friends?

Comment: @FumbleFingers LOL, Best Friends Forever! :)

Comment: Oh, bummer, I had hoped that this would start a vicious flame war ending with one of the parties tracking down the other in the real world and brutally killing him, while the rest of us on the forum watched for vicarious thrills. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd just say "free speech." Choose function over form; getting the meaning right is more important than hewing to the one-word meme, if communication is the intent.

Comment: Free speech works really well!

Answer (score 3):

How about *[liberty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberty)*?

M-W definition [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liberty):

> the quality or state of being free:
>
> a : the power to do as one pleases
>
> c : freedom from arbitrary or despotic control 
>   d : the positive enjoyment of various social, political, or economic rights and privileges

Comment: Well, but "liberty" is surely broader and more general than "freedom of speech". You could say that a society has "liberty" because people have freedom of religion, freedom of association, the right to vote, etc, etc, even though they don't have freedom of speech. Likewise one could imagine a society where people have freedom of speech but few other freedoms, and one could reasonably say that that society does not have libertty.

Answer (score 3):

I think in this context, your best choice is "expression". Censorship restricts or prohibits expression. If you can live with two words, "free expression" works nicely.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the input! Really helpful stuff! :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you want to use the word, [permissiveness](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/permissiveness#permissive) might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

*Noncensorship* is found in [some books listed by ngrams](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22noncensorship%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2003,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en)

Answer (score 0):

I would say **tolerance** to describe  an attribute of such a positive society which does not indulge in censorship. Other options could be **maturity**, in a broader sense; or **liberty of life**.

Answer (score 0):

The only one-word antonym I can think of is "sanction", but I don't think that works in this case. It only applies to a single instance. That is, you can say, "The government censored the publication of this book" versus "The government sanctioned the publication of this book". But I've never heard someone say, "I believe in the right to vote and sanction" as an alternative to "... the right to vote and freedom of speech".

Answer (score 0):

As with many nouns, censorship, the  application of censoring..., has no antonyms. One will will be compelled to find a combination of words, unless the context allows for a foreign word, which in the case at hand, is doubtful. A hyphenated word combination or phrase is likely the closest to a single word that could be found, as the other posts attest.

Press or speech laissez-faire would be an expression which seems to run quite rigorously as a reversal of meaning of censorship.

Answer (score -1):

[*Latitude*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latitude?show=0&t=1331739569%22) (see meaning 4). And an upvote for *permissiveness*.

Answer (score -2):

**Diligence** is the antonym for censorship. Censorship is any attempt to under value the works of others.

Notice the prefix Di means *two*. Diligence is the ability to respect another and one's self as *two*. With diligence in place one cannot project one's own limitations upon others.

The suffix in "diligent" is gent similar to gentleman one whom can talk out their problems instead of committing savage acts of ignorance such as censorship.

**Autonomy** describes the surrounding conditions of no censorship.